# Right assert for testing Doctrine entities in Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm writing some test for my entities and this is the code:

```
$device = new Device();
$strTool = new StringTools();

$imei = $strTool->randomNumber(17);
$device->setImei($imei);
$device->setDescription($strTool->generateRandomString(50));

$this->em->persist($device);
$this->em->flush();

$devices = $this->em->getRepository('DeviceBundle:Device')->findOneBy(array('imei' => $imei));

$this->assertCount(1, $devices);
$this->assertTrue(is_object($device));
```

But first test `assertCount` is failing with this message:

> PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of
>   PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertCount() must be a countable or
>   traversable

What is the right way to test I get results from DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findOneBy` return only one element, use `findBy` instead.

btw, what you are testing here is Doctrine itself. Doctrine is pretty well tested so there is no need for you to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to test my entities to see if their are properly mapped and so on, how did you test entities?

Comment: There's no need to test your entities unless your setter or getter add extra logic (ex: `getFullName = getFirstname.' '.getLastname`). However you need to test, for example, custom methods inside your entities repositories (ex: `getPostWithTheMostComments`).